# Error PHP website crawler class using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I'm getting the following error when trying to use Simple HTML Dom inside a web crawler class. The class seems to be working well but I get many errors in my error_log file.

```
[01-Apr-2016 23:16:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/scrybs/public_html/order/uploader/php/simple_html_dom.php on line 357
```

If I check Simple HTML Dom, the error comes from here:

```
function innertext()
    {
        if (isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_INNER])) return $this->_[HDOM_INFO_INNER];
        if (isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT])) return $this->dom->restore_noise($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT]);

        $ret = '';
        foreach ($this->nodes as $n)
            $ret .= $n->outertext();
        return $ret;
    }
```

The crawler class in question is as following:

```
class crawler
{
    protected $_url;
    protected $_depth;
    protected $_host;
    protected $_useHttpAuth = false;
    protected $_user;
    protected $_pass;
    protected $_seen = array();
    protected $_filter = array();
    public $contenu = array();

    public function __construct($url, $depth = 5)
    {
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_depth = $depth;
        $parse = parse_url($url);
        $this->_host = $parse['host'];
        $this->html = new simple_html_dom();
    }

    protected function _processAnchors($content, $url, $depth)
    {
        //$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        //@$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        //$dom->formatOutput = true;
        $this->html->load($content);

        $metatitle = $this->html->find('title',0)->innertext;
        foreach($this->html->find("meta[name='description']") as $element){
            $metadescription = $element->content;
        }
        foreach($this->html->find("meta[name='keywords']") as $element){
            $metakeywords = $element->content;
        }

        if(!empty($metatitle)){                         
            $this->contenu['meta_titles'][] = $metatitle;
        }
        if(!empty($metadescription)){
            $this->contenu['meta_titles'][] = $metadescription;
        }
        if(!empty($metakeywords)){
            $this->contenu['meta_titles'][] = $metakeywords;
        }

        // IMAGE ALTS
        foreach($this->html->find('img') as $e){
            if(!empty($e->alt)){
                if(!$this->search_array($e->alt, $this->contenu)){
                    $this->contenu['alt_images'][] = $e->alt;
                }
            }
        }

        // LINKS
        $links = $this->html->find('a');
        foreach($links as $element){ 
            // GET LINK TEXTS
            $a = $element->innertext;
            $a = preg_replace("/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/", '\1', $a);
            $a = preg_replace("/<p.*?>.*?<\/p>/", "{{P}}", $a);
            $a = preg_replace("/<img.*?>/", "{{IMG}}", $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', "{{BR}}", $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<button.*?>.*?</button>#i', '{{BUTTON}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<time.*?>(.*?)</time>#i', '{{TIME}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<span.*?>(.*?)</span>#i', '{{SPAN}}\1{{/SPAN}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<strong.*?>(.*?)</strong>#i', '{{STRONG}}\1{{/STRONG}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<b.*?>(.*?)</b>#i', '{{B}}\1{{/B}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<i.*?>(.*?)</i>#i', '{{I}}\1{{/I}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<small.*?>(.*?)</small>#i', '{{SMALL}}\1{{/SMALL}}', $a);
            $a = preg_replace('#<abbr.*?>(.*?)</abbr>#i', '{{ABBR}}\1{{/ABBR}}', $a);
            $a = trim(strip_tags($a));
            $a = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $a);
                // CHECK IF NOT ONLY VARIABLES AND SPACES
                $atmp = strip_tags($a);
                $atmp = preg_replace("/{{.*?}}/", '', $atmp);
                $atmp = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $atmp);
            if(!empty($a) && $a != '' && $atmp != ''){
                if(!$this->search_array($a, $this->contenu)){
                    $this->contenu['link_texts'][] = $a;
                }
            }

            // GET LINK TITLES
            $title = $element->title;
            if(!empty($title)){
                if(!$this->search_array($title, $this->contenu)){
                    $this->contenu['link_titles'][] = $title;
                }
            }

            $href = $element->href;
                if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
                    $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
                    if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                        $href = http_build_url($url, array('path' => $path));
                    } else {
                        $parts = parse_url($url);
                        $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                        if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) {
                            $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                        }
                        $href .= $parts['host'];
                        if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                            $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                        }
                        $href .= $path;
                    }
                }
            // Crawl only link that belongs to the start domain
            $this->crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
        }
        return $this->contenu;
    }

    protected function _getContent($url)
    {
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        if ($this->_useHttpAuth) {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->_user . ":" . $this->_pass);
        }
        // follows 302 redirect, creates problem wiht authentication
//        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        // return the content
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        // response total time
        $time = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
        /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($handle);
        return array($response, $httpCode, $time);
    }

    protected function _printResult($url, $depth, $httpcode, $time)
    {
        ob_end_flush();
        $currentDepth = $this->_depth - $depth;
        $count = count($this->_seen);
        //echo "N::$count,CODE::$httpcode,TIME::$time,DEPTH::$currentDepth URL::$url <br>";
        ob_start();
        flush();
    }

    protected function isValid($url, $depth)
    {
        if (strpos($url, $this->_host) === false
            || $depth === 0
            || isset($this->_seen[$url])
            || preg_match("/#/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/.png/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/.jpg/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/.jpeg/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/.gif/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/.pdf/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/javascript/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/twitter.com/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/google.com/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/facebook.com/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/youtube.com/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/instagram.com/i", $url)
            || preg_match("/wp-login.php/i", $url)
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($this->_filter as $excludePath) {
            if (strpos($url, $excludePath) !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
         if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
              return true;
         }
         foreach($haystack as $element) {
              if(is_array($element) && $this->search_array($needle, $element))
                   return true;
         }
       return false;
    }

    public function crawl_page($url, $depth)
    {
        if (!$this->isValid($url, $depth)) {
            return;
        }
        // add to the seen URL
        $this->_seen[$url] = true;
        // get Content and Return Code
        list($content, $httpcode, $time) = $this->_getContent($url);
        // print Result for current Page
        //$this->_printResult($url, $depth, $httpcode, $time);
        // process subPages
        $this->_processAnchors($content, $url, $depth, $contenu = array());
    }

    public function addFilterPath($path)
    {
        $this->_filter[] = $path;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->crawl_page($this->_url, $this->_depth);
    }
}
```

The error seems to be coming from this line related to innertext function:

```
// GET LINK TEXTS
$a = $element->innertext;
```

I don't get any error when I use:

```
 $a = $element->innertext;
```

But not ideal as I would like to keep HTML tags. I don't get any error when I use Simple HTML Dom outside the class so does it have something to do with the fact that Simple HTML Dom is in a class? Do somebody have an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the processed url? Also, I see that you have DOMDocument lines commented: you have tried also with DOM?

Comment: @fusion3k I tried with DOMDocument but I find it way more complicated to get the result I want, as it needs some tricks to get the inner text of HTML tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the bug.

On my (limited) tests, the problem happens when you set *depth* > 1, so — seeing your code — when you load more than one page URL. One of the countless *Simple HTML DOM* problems, is that `->load()` method doesn't work correctly on multiple loads.

Re-instantiating `html` object, the script seems work:

```
protected function _processAnchors( $content, $url, $depth )
{
    $this->html = new simple_html_dom();                                    # <-----
    $this->html->load( $content );
```

I tested also `$this->html = str_get_html($content);` but it works only on limited sites.

Additional Note: In HTML `<title>` tag is mandatory, but not all sites has well formatted HTML: consider checking for `<title>` tag (and for each tag) existence to avoid additional errors.

Comment: Working like a charm!! Hats off! Thanks a lot.